# Is there any way to extract a specfic pattern in a given String using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How do i get values which has M at the end using Regex.

For example

some_str = '/dev/root               298.0M    210.9M     67.3M  76% /'

From above string i want to exact 298.0M , 210.9M and 67.M using Python Regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re
pat = '([0-9]+.[0-9]+[M])'
re.findall(pat, "/dev/root 298.0M 210.9M 67.3M 76% /")
```

Output:

```
['298.0M', '210.9M', '67.3M']
```

Comment: Thanks @bigbounty . it worked